# How can I get unbanned from a Minecraft PE server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was playing in this Minecraft PE server, where this guy was killing me non stop. I got frustrated and hit him back, which got me banned from the server.

Unfortunately I did a lot of work on the server, but now I'm banned. How do I get unbanned? Is it possible?

Comment: The only way to get unbanned is by contacting the server admin and ask him to unban you.

Comment: @5pike - That'd make a good answer :)

Comment: The problem is how do I enter the server and ask him?

Comment: In most cases, if you type in a domain for a server, the same domain might have some contact information.  So like minecraftpe.randomwebaddress.egg means that you might want to Google the "randomwebaddress.egg" part and see if there's a site there.  On the other hand, you where getting killed over and over again, and attacking back got you banned.  It might not be worth going back to a power-abusive admin like that.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get unbanned is by contacting the server admin and ask him to unban you.

Comment: Idk how to contact the admin

Comment: @user118966 - We don't know either.